# ActionCable unable to call on periodic timers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

This is not documented in Rails, but ActionCable has a module called `PeriodicTimers`
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/lib/action_cable/channel/periodic_timers.rb

Now in my `app/channels/requests_channel.rb` I have attempted to test this out by doing:

```
class RequestsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  periodically :transmit_status, every: 2.seconds

  def subscribed
      stream_from "requests_#{current_user.id}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
  end

  private

  def transmit_status
    puts "ping"
  end
end
```

and when I connect and subscribe to the stream, nothing shows up in the console. I felt like the code in ActionCable was fairly straight forward, and that this should work  but I'm unable to get it to work. Anybody have any experience with this?

Comment: I've looked into this for several hours, trying to understand why this doesn't not work. I too wanted to setup periodic timers.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 5.2.0, both

```
  periodically every: 5.seconds do
    transmit payload: 'some_payload'
  end
```

And,

```
periodically :transmit_device_status, every: 5.seconds

def transmit_device_status
  transmit payload: 'some_payload'
end
```

Worked for me on the first try. I can't tell you why it wasn't working for you initially sorry, but it might help someone else since this is one of the very few posts I found on the subject.